# True Tone switches off after standby on external display

Tags: display, sleep-wake

When my macbook pro goes on after standby there is no yellow tint on the external monitor and I have do disable and reenable true tone in settings to get it back (there is actually a yellow tint coming from f.lux but less strong then with true tone activated).
I am using f.lux and had SwitchResX installed which still appears in monitor name after uninstalling.
The Monitor is a an Acer with 4K connected with DP to usb-c cable and running with 60Hz

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running, which MBP model do you have? Also, when did the behaviour start, and does it have an effect if you disable/uninstall f.lux?

Comment: latest macOS, MBP from 2020 with intel and 16inch. I just got aware of this behaviour after last update, but didn't pay attention to TT before and assumed it was off. Don't want to uninstall f.lux the inconvenience is not so great